# getRuntime().exec and Processbuilder returning only 2 line of data

Tags: android

I tried to get a top command output and display it in the UI. But when I run the below code(Runtime.exec & processbuilder) it gives only two line of result.

Can anyone help me with this?
`

```
     String command = "ps";
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    try {
        Process process = pb.start();
        process.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            topcommandoutput.append(line+"\n");
        }

        reader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

AND

```
    String command =  "top -s cpu -n 1 -m " + noofprocess;
   Process p;
   try {
       String line = "";
       p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( command);
       p.waitFor();

       Scanner reader = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

       while ((line = reader.nextLine())!= "null") {
           topcommandoutput.append(line+"\n");
       }
       ParseText(timestamp);
   } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

`

Comment: No answer so far. There is a code right above the Summary section that you could use. It redirects your output to a file in Android: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ProcessBuilder

Comment: What are you expecting to see that is missing

Comment: I am running the below command
top -s cpu -n 1 -m 5
expecting output like this.
User 2%, System 10%, IOW 0%, IRQ 0%
User 2 + Nice 0 + Sys 8 + Idle 67 + IOW 0 + IRQ 0 + SIRQ 0 = 77

  PID USER     PR  NI CPU% S  #THR     VSS     RSS PCY Name
10954 shell    20   0  14% R     1   5204K   1664K  fg top
   10 root     20   0   1% S     1      0K      0K  fg rcuop/0
    3 root     20   0   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg ksoftirqd/0
    5 root      0 -20   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg kworker/0:0H
    7 root     20   0   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg rcu_preempt